# Authenticating Solidity params and signatures within smart contract

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

I'm trying to build a sort-of meta-transaction architecture where an admin can trustlessly submit someone else's transaction with validated data. Basic Solidity and JS code below. I'm missing a piece somewhere as the signature verification (`require(recoverSigner(signedHash, _signature) == _signer);`) fails, but not sure where it goes wrong

...

Basic contract version:

```
contract Account {
  struct User {
    string username;
  }

  function createAccount(
    address _signer,
    User _user,
    uint256 _nonce,
    bytes memory _signature
  ) {
    bytes32 messageHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_user, _nonce));
    bytes32 signedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", _messageHash));
    require(recoverSigner(signedHash, _signature) == _signer);
    ...

  }

    function recoverSigner(
        bytes32 _ethSignedMessageHash,
        bytes memory _signature
    ) public pure returns (address) {
        (bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint8 v) = splitSignature(_signature);

        return ecrecover(_ethSignedMessageHash, v, r, s);
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        public
        pure
        returns (
            bytes32 r,
            bytes32 s,
            uint8 v
        )
    {
        require(sig.length == 65, "invalid signature length");

        assembly {
            /*
            First 32 bytes stores the length of the signature

            add(sig, 32) = pointer of sig + 32
            effectively, skips first 32 bytes of signature

            mload(p) loads next 32 bytes starting at the memory address p into memory
            */

            // first 32 bytes, after the length prefix
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            // second 32 bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            // final byte (first byte of the next 32 bytes)
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        // implicitly return (r, s, v)
    }
}
```

Basic JS script:

```
const userEncoded = ethers.utils.AbiCoder.prototype.encode(
  ['string'],
  ['abc']
);
const nonce = 1;
const hashedMessage = ethers.utils.keccak256(userEncoded, nonce);
const signedMessage = await user1.signMessage(hashedMessage);

await account.connect(admin).createAccount(user1.address, { username: 'abc' }), nonce, signedMessage);
```